# troubleshooting mysql error 1064

Tags: mysql

I have been unable to get a PHP call to work. I decided to try and execute the command via a command prompt.

Here is what I tried and what was returned:

```
mysql> -u setlist -p music -D setlist
    -> INSERT INTO main (name, orderno, midi)VALUES ("second", "third", "fourth");
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-u setlist -p music -D setlist
INSERT INTO main (name, orderno, midi)VALUES ("se' at line 1
```

I've tried all quote combinations that I can think of.  Does anyone have any suggestions of what my problem might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mysql options `-u setlist -p music -D setlist` as part of your command that's why it's failing. And the error clearly states that. Therefore login to mysql correctly and make sure that your INSERT is the only command in the prompt before you execute it. Like this

```
mysql> INSERT INTO main (name, orderno, midi) VALUES ("second", "third", "fourth");
```

To open `mysql` and choose the database on connection use:

```
mysql -u username -p dbname
                    ^ no password specified mysql will prompt you for it
```

or

```
mysql -u username -ppassword dbname
```

To choose database in mysql use

```
USE dbname;
```

Comment: Select a database first. You can do it either by specifying its name in command line or by executing a command `USE dbname;` in mysql

Comment: Your database's name is `setlist`, correct? Or is it `music`?

Comment: the user name and database name are both setlist.  the p is music

Comment: Start mysql like this `mysql -u setlist -pmusic setlist`. And then execute your commands. Make sure there is **NO SPACE** between -p and music.